# How to connect to MongoDB using Node.js written in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm working on a Node.js server, connecting to MongoDB and written with TypeScript. When I try to use MongoDB it doesn't create a connection, however when I check the mongo output it does appear to create a connection.

What am I missing in my code to define the connection in Node.js?

My connection string is `'mongodb://localhost:27017'`

My connection method:

```
connect() {
    console.log('connecting to mongo') //this is called
    MongoClient.connect(this.connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(client => {
        console.log('setting client'); //this doesn't get called
        this.client = client;
        console.log(this.client);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error during connecting to mongo: '); //this also doesn't get called
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Mongo output:

> 2018-11-08T23:06:24.106+0100 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51345 #11 (2 connections now open)
>
> 2018-11-08T23:06:24.107+0100 I NETWORK  [conn11] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:51345 conn11: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.9" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "17.7.0" }, platform: "Node.js v8.9.3, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.8" }

My repository is at https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/MEAN-ToDo/blob/master/server/src/db/mongo.db.ts for the full code.

**`console.log(db)` as asked by shkaper**

```
MongoClient {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s:
   { url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
     options:
      { servers: [Array],
        caseTranslate: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        socketTimeoutMS: 360000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     dbCache: {},
     sessions: [] },
  topology:
   Server {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { serverOpening: [Function],
        serverDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function],
        serverClosed: [Function],
        topologyOpening: [Function],
        topologyClosed: [Function],
        topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        commandStarted: [Function],
        commandSucceeded: [Function],
        commandFailed: [Function],
        joined: [Function],
        left: [Function],
        ping: [Function],
        ha: [Function],
        authenticated: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        parseError: [Function],
        open: [Object],
        fullsetup: [Object],
        all: [Object],
        reconnect: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 25,
     _maxListeners: Infinity,
     clientInfo:
      { driver: [Object],
        os: [Object],
        platform: 'Node.js v8.9.3, LE' },
     s:
      { coreTopology: [Object],
        sCapabilities: null,
        clonedOptions: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        poolSize: 5,
        storeOptions: [Object],
        store: [Object],
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        options: [Object],
        sessionPool: [Object],
        sessions: [],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] } } }
```

Comment: can we see the console output from your application?

Comment: Doesn't seems a problem with the code, Are you trying to connect to remote `mongodb` hosted on another server?

Comment: Add a line with `console.log(db)` after this line: https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/MEAN-ToDo/blob/master/server/src/controllers/to-do.controller.ts#L11 and share the output please

Comment: @shkaper I added the output

Comment: @SureshPrajapati I'm trying to connect to localhost, I added the connection string I'm using

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-node-express-typescript-api

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is because `mongo.connect` is async code and controller call it wrongly. so the subsequent line `mongo.getDb()` will be executed without having `this.client` initiated properly.

Since you use Typescript, we can use `async/await` for cleaner code.

```
async connect() { // add async
    console.log('connecting to mongo');

    try {
      if (!this.client) { // I added this extra check
        console.log('setting client');
        this.client = await MongoClient.connect(this.connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true })
        console.log(this.client);      
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log('error during connecting to mongo: ');
      console.error(error);
    }    
}
```

And in controller code

```
async get(req: Request, res: Response) { // add async
  const mongo = new MongoDb();
  await mongo.connect(); // add await
  const db = mongo.db(); 
  // ....     
}
```

I tried your repo with the changes and got this response

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: This is by far the best solution. I already used! good catch @deerawan!

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said about neither error nor success callbacks being called, I think the problem is not only in code here: https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/MEAN-ToDo/blob/master/server/src/db/mongo.db.ts
But also e.g. here: https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/MEAN-ToDo/blob/master/server/src/controllers/to-do.controller.ts
When you run `mongo.connect` there should be an option to wait for the promise returned from `MongoClient.connect`. So I would change code in `mongo.db.ts` to for example sth like this (it depends how you want to handle this promise):

```
connect() {
    console.log('connecting to mongo')
    return MongoClient.connect(this.connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(client => {
        console.log('setting client');
        this.client = client;
        console.log(this.client);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error during connecting to mongo: ');
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Then in `to-do.controller.ts` you can `await` this or use `then`:

```
get(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const mongo = new MongoDb();
    mongo.connect().then(() => {

      const db = mongo.getDb();
      const collection = db.collection('todo', (error, collection) => {
          if (error) {
              res.json(error);
              res.statusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
              return;
          }

          collection.find().toArray((error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                  res.json(error);
                  res.statusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
              }

              res.json(result);
              res.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
          })

      });

      mongo.close();
    });
}
```

I suppose that your code just does not "wait" for connection to be established and then fails.

Comment: This is a good one based on the requests made on the original question!

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions do work but there is another method that I like a bit better. It more resembles a standard HTTP call (I've gotten it to work with and without the async-await, but it's a good idea to leave it in):

```
private async connect(){
    this.mongo = new mongodb.MongoClient(this.url, {useNewParser: true});
    await this.mongo.connect((err, client) => {
        if(client.isConnected()){
            console.log('setting client');
            this.client = client;
            console.log(this.client);
        }
        else{
            console.log('error during connecting to mongo: ');
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

This is based off the Node.js driver api v3.2 that you can look over here:
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/index.html

It might just be a different way of shaving a cat but I figure it's worth sharing for anyone else who ends up here later.